# Azure ARM Template : Output of a resource passed as input of another in the same template file

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to build an ARM template file for my Azure project. My requirement here is to,

1. Create a Log Analytics Workspace
2. Create an Automation Account
3. Create a variable in the Automation Account that stores the workspace id of Log Analytics Workspace.

This is pretty simple via portal but is there a way to do the same using ARM Templates?
I am using the below code but I get "Invalid JSON - Kindly check the value of the variable." error.

Here's the below ARM template snippet:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/variables",
    "apiVersion": "2022-08-08",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('automationAccount_name'), '/', parameters('automationAccount_logAnalytics_workspaceId_variable_name'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccount_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "isEncrypted": true,
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', parameters(<workspace_name>))).customerId]",
        "description": "The Workspace ID of Log Analytics Workspace."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [arm template](https://buildvirtual.net/azure-automation-account-arm-template/), I created a template with few changes to link workspace and automation account by storing in a variable and was able to do it successfully as follows:

***deploy.json:***

```bash
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('workspace')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-01-13-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('automationAccount')]",
      "location": "[parameters('automationAccountLocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('workspace')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "Basic"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/linkedServices",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('workspace'), '/' , 'Automation')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('workspace')]",
        "[parameters('automationAccount')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccount'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

***Parameters.json***:

```bash
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"sku": {
"value": "xxxx"
},
"workspace": {
"value": "myworkspace"
},
"automationAccount": {
"value": "myautomation"
  }
 }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

***Output after deployment:***

[image]